# How to reload content of SlideNavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

Actually i have created slide navigation by using this [Slide Navigationcontroller](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/slidenavigationcontroller)

Now everything is working fine i have adjusted slide to left menu. but when i want to change it's content then at a time it does not work.

i have used this code in appdelegates for setting left menu and attached slidenavigation controller using storyboard as a root view controller of as a navigation controller

```
  mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
    employeeSlideNavigation *leftMenu = (employeeSlideNavigation*)[mainStoryboard
                                                                   instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"employeeSlideNavigation"];
    [SlideNavigationController sharedInstance].leftMenu = leftMenu;
    [SlideNavigationController sharedInstance].menuRevealAnimationDuration = .18;
```

Please suggest me how to reload left menu content. actually this code is in

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
 {

 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this

Add observer with method inside the slideController class

```
#define NOTIFICATION_UPDATESLIDE @"UpdateSlideTable"

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(updateDetails:) name:NOTIFICATION_UPDATESLIDE object:nil];

-(void)updateDetails:(NSNotification*)notification
{
           //content which you need to update
}
```

and post the notification from where you want to update the content of slide menu.
like this

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:NOTIFICATION_UPDATESLIDE object:self];
```

Hope this helps you.